# Regex to isolate specific word in body of text until delimiter

Tags: php, regex

I have the following specific output from which I would like to isolate from and including the word "industry" (whichever case) and the sub string until the next delimiter typically "|". I get the $output from an API So the contents of $output are always different but the generic expression may be something like: blah blah blah |industry = industry info| blah blah blah. If the word industry exists in the output I would just like to get industry = industry info. Is there a generic regex which can do this? The specific output I have returned is:

```
<?php

$output = '{{other uses|UBS (disambiguation)}} {{Use dmy dates|date=April  
2015}} {{Infobox company |name = UBS Group AG |logo = [[File:UBS 
Logo.svg|200px|UBS Group AG Logo]] |type = [[Aktiengesellschaft]] 
([[Aktiengesellschaft|AG]])
[[Public company]] |traded_as = {{SWX|UBSG}} {{SWX|UBSN}}
{{nyse|UBS}} |foundation=1854 |predecessor = [[Union Bank of 
Switzerland]] and [[Swiss Bank Corporation]] merged in 1998;  
[[PaineWebber]] merged in 2000 |location = [[ZÃ¼rich]]
[[Basel]] |key_people = [[Axel A. Weber]] (Chairman){{br}}[[Sergio   
Ermotti]] (CEO) {{br}} |area_served = Worldwide |industry =[[Banking]], 
[[Financial services]] |products = [[Investment Banking]]
[[Investment Management]] [[Wealth Management]] [[Private Banking]]
[[Commercial Bank|Corporate Banking]]
[[Private Equity]]
[[Finance and Insurance]]
[[Retail Banking|Consumer Banking]]
[[Mortgage loans|Mortgages]]
[[Credit Cards]] |revenue = {{Increase}} [[Swiss franc|CHF]]28.027  
billion (2014) |operating_income = {{Decrease}} CHF2.461 billion (2014) 
{{cite web|title=UBS Annual Report 
2014|url=http://www.ubs.com/global/en/about_ubs/
investor_relations/annualreporting/2014/_jcr_content/par/
columncontrol_0/col1/linklist/link.1899571414.file/
bGluay9wYXRoPS9jb250ZW50L2RhbS9zdGF0aWMvZ2xvYmFsL2ludmV
zdG9yX3JlbGF0aW9ucy9hbm51YWwyMDE0L2FubnVhbC1yZXBv
cnQtZ3JvdXAtMjAxNC1lbi5wZGY=/annual-report-group-2014-      
en.pdf|publisher=UBS.com|accessdate=May 3, 2015}} 
|assets = {{Increase}} CHF1.062 trillion (2014) |equity = {{Increase}} 
CHF54.368 billion (2014) |num_employees = {{Decrease}} 60,155 (2014) 
|caption=We Will Not Rest |homepage = [https://www.ubs.com/ UBS.com] }}  
'''UBS AG''' is a Swiss global [[financial services]] company, 
incorporated in the [[Canton of Zurich]],{{cite web|title=Trade Register: 
UBS AG|url=http://www.moneyhouse.ch/en/u/ubs_ag_CH-270.3.004.646-4.htm}}   
and co-headquartered in [[ZÃ¼rich]] and [[Basel]].{{cite 
web|url=https://www.ubs.com/global/en/about_ubs/
investor_relations/faq/about.html|title=Corporate information - UBS 
Global topics|work=ubs.com|accessdate=March 29, 2015}} The company 
provides [[investment banking]], [[asset management]], and [[wealth 
management]] services for private, corporate, and institutional clients 
worldwide, and for retail clients in Switzerland as well.{{cite 
web|url=https://www.ubs.com/global/en/about_ubs/
investor_relations/our_businesses.html|title=Our clients & businesses -   
UBS Global topics|work=ubs.com|
accessdate=March 29, 2015}} The name ''UBS'' was originally an 
abbreviation for the [[Union Bank of Switzerland]], but it ceased to be a 
representational abbreviation after the bank's merger with [[Swiss Bank 
Corporation]] in 1998. The company traces its origins to 1856, when the 
earliest of its predecessor banks was founded.{{cite web|title=150 years 
of banking tradition|url=https://www.ubs.com/global/en/about_ubs/
about_us/history/_jcr_content/rightpar/
teaser_0/linklist/link.651908116.file/
bGluay9wYXRoPS9jb250ZW50L2RhbS91YnMvZ2xvY
mFsL2Fib3V0X3Vicy9hYm91dF91cy9oaXN0b3J5X29mX3
Vicy8xNTBfeWVhcnNfb2ZfYmFua2luZ19FTkcucGRm/
150_years_of_banking_ENG.pdf|work=ubs.com|
accessdate=March 29, 2015}} UBS is the biggest
bank in Switzerland, operating in more than 50 
countries with about 60,000 employees around the world, as of 2014.{{cite 
web|title=About us: UBS in a few 
words|url=https://www.ubs.com/global/en/
about_ubs/about_us/ourprofile.html|work=ubs.com}} It is considered the 
world's largest manager of private wealth assets, with over [[Swiss 
franc|CHF]]2.2 trillion in invested assets,J.P.Morgan Cazenove Europe';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[^|]*\bindustry\b[^|]*
```

Try this.See demo.Use `i` flag.

https://regex101.com/r/uF4oY4/79

This will match a `string` which starts from after `|` has `industry` till the next `|`.

```
$re = "/[^|]*\\bindustry\\b[^|]*/i"; 
$str = "{{other uses|UBS (disambiguation)}} {{Use dmy dates|date=April  \n2015}} {{Infobox company |name = UBS Group AG |logo = [[File:UBS \nLogo.svg|200px|UBS Group AG Logo]] |type = [[Aktiengesellschaft]] \n([[Aktiengesellschaft|AG]])\n[[Public company]] |traded_as = {{SWX|UBSG}} {{SWX|UBSN}}\n{{nyse|UBS}} |foundation=1854 |predecessor = [[Union Bank of \nSwitzerland]] and [[Swiss Bank Corporation]] merged in 1998;  \n[[PaineWebber]] merged in 2000 |location = [[ZÃ¼rich]]\n[[Basel]] |key_people = [[Axel A. Weber]] (Chairman){{br}}[[Sergio   \nErmotti]] (CEO) {{br}} |area_served = Worldwide |industry =[[Banking]], \n[[Financial services]] |products = [[Investment Banking]]\n[[Investment Management]] [[Wealth Management]] [[Private Banking]]\n[[Commercial Bank|Corporate Banking]]\n[[Private Equity]]\n[[Finance and Insurance]]\n[[Retail Banking|Consumer Banking]]\n[[Mortgage loans|Mortgages]]\n[[Credit Cards]] |revenue = {{Increase}} [[Swiss franc|CHF]]28.027  \nbillion (2014) |operating_income = {{Decrease}} CHF2.461 billion (2014) \n{{cite web|title=UBS Annual Report \n2014|url=http://www.ubs.com/global/en/about_ubs/\ninvestor_relations/annualreporting/2014/_jcr_content/par/\ncolumncontrol_0/col1/linklist/link.1899571414.file/\nbGluay9wYXRoPS9jb250ZW50L2RhbS9zdGF0aWMvZ2xvYmFsL2ludmV\nzdG9yX3JlbGF0aW9ucy9hbm51YWwyMDE0L2FubnVhbC1yZXBv\ncnQtZ3JvdXAtMjAxNC1lbi5wZGY=/annual-report-group-2014-      \nen.pdf|publisher=UBS.com|accessdate=May 3, 2015}} \n|assets = {{Increase}} CHF1.062 trillion (2014) |equity = {{Increase}} \nCHF54.368 billion (2014) |num_employees = {{Decrease}} 60,155 (2014) \n|caption=We Will Not Rest |homepage = [https://www.ubs.com/ UBS.com] }}  \n'''UBS AG''' is a Swiss global [[financial services]] company, \nincorporated in the [[Canton of Zurich]],{{cite web|title=Trade Register: \nUBS AG|url=http://www.moneyhouse.ch/en/u/ubs_ag_CH-270.3.004.646-4.htm}}   \nand co-headquartered in [[ZÃ¼rich]] and [[Basel]].{{cite \nweb|url=https://www.ubs.com/global/en/about_ubs/\ninvestor_relations/faq/about.html|title=Corporate information - UBS \nGlobal topics|work=ubs.com|accessdate=March 29, 2015}} The company \nprovides [[investment banking]], [[asset management]], and [[wealth \nmanagement]] services for private, corporate, and institutional clients \nworldwide, and for retail clients in Switzerland as well.{{cite \nweb|url=https://www.ubs.com/global/en/about_ubs/\ninvestor_relations/our_businesses.html|title=Our clients & businesses -   \nUBS Global topics|work=ubs.com|\naccessdate=March 29, 2015}} The name ''UBS'' was originally an \nabbreviation for the [[Union Bank of Switzerland]], but it ceased to be a \nrepresentational abbreviation after the bank's merger with [[Swiss Bank \nCorporation]] in 1998. The company traces its origins to 1856, when the \nearliest of its predecessor banks was founded.{{cite web|title=150 years \nof banking tradition|url=https://www.ubs.com/global/en/about_ubs/\nabout_us/history/_jcr_content/rightpar/\nteaser_0/linklist/link.651908116.file/\nbGluay9wYXRoPS9jb250ZW50L2RhbS91YnMvZ2xvY\nmFsL2Fib3V0X3Vicy9hYm91dF91cy9oaXN0b3J5X29mX3\nVicy8xNTBfeWVhcnNfb2ZfYmFua2luZ19FTkcucGRm/\n150_years_of_banking_ENG.pdf|work=ubs.com|\naccessdate=March 29, 2015}} UBS is the biggest\nbank in Switzerland, operating in more than 50 \ncountries with about 60,000 employees around the world, as of 2014.{{cite \nweb|title=About us: UBS in a few \nwords|url=https://www.ubs.com/global/en/\nabout_ubs/about_us/ourprofile.html|work=ubs.com}} It is considered the \nworld's largest manager of private wealth assets, with over [[Swiss \nfranc|CHF]]2.2 trillion in invested assets,J.P.Morgan Cazenove Europ"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: 340K steps for the current input: are you sure a regex solution is the best here? If the input is a bit larger, catastrophic backtracking is imminent.

Comment: @stribizhev guess that's a question for OP.He has tagged it regex.You can offer another solution if you have

Comment: Absolutely perfect! Thanks you very much!!

Answer (score 1):

I would not apply a regex on a large input string like yours. As you can see in the regex debugger, vks' regex makes about 340,000 steps to finally fetch you a result.

I suggest splitting the string with `|` first, and then grepping out the info you need.

```
$chks = explode("|", $output);
foreach ($chks as $chk) {
if (strpos($chk,'industry =') !== false) {
    echo $chk;
}
```

}
Result:

```
industry =[[Banking]], 
[[Financial services]]
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/K3QWc4)